# Error after migration from ERB to HAML

Tags: ruby, haml, erb

The working ERB before the convert :

```html
<table class="tabularData tabularData--tableInner">
   <tbody>
     <%= content_tag :tr do
       concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.account_number'), width: "180")
       concat content_tag(:td, consumer.account_number)
     end if consumer.account_number %>
 
     <%= content_tag :tr do
       concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.paybyvouchers_id'))
       concat content_tag(:td, consumer.paybyvouchers_id)
     end if consumer.paybyvouchers_id %>
 
     <%= content_tag :tr do
       concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.created_on'), width: "180")
       concat content_tag(:td, display_date(consumer.created_at)[:defaultFormat])
     end %>
 
     <%= content_tag :tr do
       concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.date_of_birth'))
       concat content_tag(:td, display_date(consumer.date_of_birth)[:defaultFormat])
     end %>
 
     <%= content_tag :tr do
       concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.age'))
       concat content_tag(:td, consumer.age.value)
     end %>
 
     <%= content_tag :tr do
       concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.preferred_language'))
       concat content_tag(:td, consumer.language.name)
     end %>
 
     <%= content_tag :tr do
       concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.country_of_nationality'))
       concat content_tag(:td, consumer.country_of_nationality.name)
     end %>
 
     <%= content_tag :tr do
       content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.address')) +
       content_tag(:td) do
         concat consumer.address_line_1
         if consumer.address_line_2.present?
           concat tag(:br, nil, true)
           concat consumer.address_line_2
         end
         concat tag(:br, nil, true)
         concat consumer.postcode
         concat tag(:br, nil, true)
         concat consumer.city
         if consumer.state.present?
           concat tag(:br, nil, true)
           concat consumer.state
         end
         concat tag(:br, nil, true)
         concat consumer.country.name
       end
     end %>
 
     <%= content_tag :tr do
       concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.primary_phone_number'))
       concat content_tag(:td, display_phone_number(consumer.primary_isd_code, consumer.primary_phone_number))
     end %>
 
     <%= content_tag :tr do
       concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.secondary_phone_number'))
       concat content_tag(:td, display_phone_number(consumer.secondary_isd_code, consumer.secondary_phone_number))
     end if consumer.secondary_phone_number %>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

Not working HAML after the convert:

And the error : /Users/app/views/shared/_consumer_personal_details_table.html.haml:3: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end ..._number'), width: "180") concat content_tag(:td, consumer.ac... ... ^

```html
%table.tabularData.tabularData--tableInner
  %tbody
    = content_tag :tr do                                                           |
        concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.account_number'), width: "180") |
        concat content_tag(:td, consumer.account_number)                           |
      end if consumer.account_number                                               |
    = content_tag :tr do                                               |
        concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.paybyvouchers_id')) |
        concat content_tag(:td, consumer.paybyvouchers_id)             |
      end if consumer.paybyvouchers_id                                 |
    = content_tag :tr do                                                           |
        concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.created_on'), width: "180")     |
        concat content_tag(:td, display_date(consumer.created_at)[:defaultFormat]) |
      end                                                                          |
    = content_tag :tr do                                                              |
        concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.date_of_birth'))                   |
        concat content_tag(:td, display_date(consumer.date_of_birth)[:defaultFormat]) |
      end                                                                             |
    = content_tag :tr do                                  |
        concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.age')) |
        concat content_tag(:td, consumer.age.value)       |
      end                                                 |
    = content_tag :tr do                                                 |
        concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.preferred_language')) |
        concat content_tag(:td, consumer.language.name)                  |
      end                                                                |
    = content_tag :tr do                                                     |
        concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.country_of_nationality')) |
        concat content_tag(:td, consumer.country_of_nationality.name)        |
      end                                                                    |
    = content_tag :tr do                                 |
        content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.address')) + |
        content_tag(:td) do                              |
          concat consumer.address_line_1                 |
          if consumer.address_line_2.present?            |
            concat tag(:br, nil, true)                   |
            concat consumer.address_line_2               |
          end                                            |
          concat tag(:br, nil, true)                     |
          concat consumer.postcode                       |
          concat tag(:br, nil, true)                     |
          concat consumer.city                           |
          if consumer.state.present?                     |
            concat tag(:br, nil, true)                   |
            concat consumer.state                        |
          end                                            |
          concat tag(:br, nil, true)                     |
          concat consumer.country.name                   |
        end                                              |
      end                                                |
    = content_tag :tr do                                                                                        |
        concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.primary_phone_number'))                                      |
        concat content_tag(:td, display_phone_number(consumer.primary_isd_code, consumer.primary_phone_number)) |
      end                                                                                                       |
    = content_tag :tr do                                                                                            |
        concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.secondary_phone_number'))                                        |
        concat content_tag(:td, display_phone_number(consumer.secondary_isd_code, consumer.secondary_phone_number)) |
      end if consumer.secondary_phone_number
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not using HAML syntax.

Instead of

```
= content_tag :tr do                                                                                            
  concat content_tag(:td, t('consumer.labels.secondary_phone_number'))                                        
  concat content_tag(:td, display_phone_number(consumer.secondary_isd_code, consumer.secondary_phone_number)) |
end if consumer.secondary_phone_number
```

write

```
- if consumer.secondary_phone_number
  %tr
    %td= t('consumer.labels.secondary_phone_number'))
    %td= display_phone_number(consumer.secondary_isd_code, consumer.secondary_phone_number))
```